# fixing front thru-axle wheel play

Tags: hub, through-axle, wobble

Recently got a Poseidon Redwood gravel bike and after about 100 miles or so I noticed some front wheel play when pushing the wheel from side to side with my hand. Took the wheel out to see if the cones were lose or something but I could not figure out how to even get the end caps of.

[The caps themselves have some play as shown in this video](https://i.imgur.com/1eeY5DD.mp4) but just the same amount on both sides so I'm not sure if that's how it's supposed to be. I don't see anywhere where I could fit an allen key or wrench/spanner to take them off and I didn't wanna force them. The hubs have Quanta branding on them but I couldn't find any guide online for them either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Most thru-axle front hubs have endcaps that pull straight off and are held in place with o-rings to gently create some friction.

You can use the thru-axle to *gently* rock them back and forth to work them off if they're sticking. On yours, if you have the kind that pull off, poking something through those holes and pulling that way should also work.

Some hubs have endcaps where one or both thread onto the main hub axle. Your symptom combined with the holes on the endcap in the video suggest yours could be like this. Try poking a tool, i.e. a 3mm allen or small screwdriver shaft, through the holes on each side and screw them towards each other and see if anything happens. If it is a hub with threaded endcaps, snug them down tight and you should be good. If not then take them off, make sure the bearings have no play and are pressed into their bores without issue, grease the contact surfaces of the endcaps and make sure they're all the way in, then put your axle on tight with greased threads and you should be fine.